# How to uninstall zend studio on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, zend-studio

I have installed latest free version of zend studio and it got expired. I can not see any uninstall program along with it. How can I uninstall it from ubuntu 11.10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends how you installed it.

if it was a .deb package, you can remove it by :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge package-name
```

otherwise you could find something in this folder :

```
cd /usr/local/Zend/ZendStudio-7.2.0\Uninstall\ Zend\ Studio\ -\ 7.2.0/
sudo sh ./Uninstall_Zend_Studio_-_7.2.0
```

source : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9559635

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just untar the zip file and executed the sh program. I can not see the uninstall program.

Answer (score 0):

ZendStudio doesn't really "install" on linux. Everything resides in the directory you extract it to. Delete the directory, it's gone without a trace.